# How to make use of a custom JsonConverter to deserialise only a child object in Json.NET?

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization, json-deserialization

I want to deserialise JSON from a web response. Here's a typical response:

```json
{
    "response": {
        "garbage": 0,
        "details": [
            {
                "id": "123456789"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

However, this format is undesirable. Ideally, the response would be just

```json
{
    "id": "123456789"
}
```

so that it could be deserialised into an object like

```cs
public class Details {
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public ulong Id { get; set; }
}
```

Since I have no control of the server (it's a public API), I aim to modify the deserialisation process to achieve my desired format.

---

I've tried to make use of a custom `JsonConverter` to accomplish this. The idea is to skip tokens until I find the desired starting point for deserialisation into `Details`. However, I'm not sure where it should be used in the deserialisation process.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace ConsoleApp2 {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            // Simulating a stream from WebResponse.
            const string json = "{"response":{"garbage":0,"details":[{"id":"123456789"}]}}";
            byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
            Stream stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);

            Details details = Deserialise<Details>(stream);

            Console.WriteLine($"ID: {details.Id}");
            Console.Read();
        }

        public static T Deserialise<T>(Stream stream) where T : class {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8)) {
                JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings {
                    MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Ignore,
                    DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None
                };

                settings.Converters.Add(new DetailConverter());
                return JsonSerializer.Create(settings).Deserialize(reader, typeof(T)) as T;
            }
        }
    }

    public class Details {
        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public ulong Id { get; set; }
    }

    public class DetailConverter : JsonConverter {
        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer,
                                       object value,
                                       JsonSerializer serializer) {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader,
                                        Type objectType,
                                        object existingValue,
                                        JsonSerializer serializer) {
            if (reader.Depth == 0) {
                while (!(reader.Path.Equals("response.details[0]", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject)) {
                    reader.Read();
                }

                try {
                    return serializer.Deserialize(reader, objectType);
                } finally {
                    reader.Read(); // EndArray - details
                    reader.Read(); // EndObject - response
                    reader.Read(); // EndObject - root
                }
            }

            return serializer.Deserialize(reader, objectType);
        }

        public override bool CanWrite => false;
        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) => true;
    }
}
```

As things stand right now, the stack overflows because `DetailConverter.ReadJson()` is being used on the same object repeatedly and it never gets deserialised. I think it's because I've set `DetailConverter` as a "global" converter through `JsonSerializerSettings`. I think the issues lies in when and how my converter is being used rather than in its inner workings.

---

I've gotten a similar `DetailConverter` to work for the following structure. However, while the array from `details` is removed, it's still undesirable because of nesting and unused properties.

```
public class Root {
    [JsonProperty("response")]
    public Response Response { get; set; }
}

public class Response {
    [JsonProperty("details")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(DetailConverter))]
    public Details Details { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("garbage")]
    public uint Garbage { get; set; }
}

public class Details {
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public ulong Id { get; set; }
}
```

I thought it'd be straightforward to scale up the converter to the entire JSON rather than just one property. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: You really should use the second approach with the default `JsonConverter`. Also, you don't have to declare "Garbage" if you are not using it — just the direct parents will do.

Comment: Even larger JSON files with a lot of nesting aren't as annoying thanks to code generators. However, creating a bunch of dummy parent classes just doesn't seem elegant.

Comment: @aaron There is a 2 day waiting period.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to clear the list of converters of the `JsonSerializer` before calling `JsonSerializer.Deserialize` from my `JsonConverter`.

I got the idea from [here](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/386#issuecomment-248018699), in which a user describes how nulling out the `JsonConverter` of a `JsonContract` reverts to the default `JsonConverter`. This avoids the problem of repeatedly calling my custom `JsonConverter` for the child object I wish to deserialise.

```
public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader,
                                Type objectType,
                                object existingValue,
                                JsonSerializer serializer) {
    while (reader.Depth != 3) {
        reader.Read();
    }

    serializer.Converters.Clear();

    return serializer.Deserialize(reader, objectType);
}
```

The code has also been simplified, removing the `try` - `finally` block. It's not necessary to read the ending tokens because there will never be an attempt to deserialise them anyway. There is also no need to check for the depth because the custom `JsonConverter` will only be used once.

Answer (score 1):

Will Linq to JSON work for you?

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var json = "{'response':{'garbage':0,'details':[{'id':'123456789'}]}}";
        var obj = JObject.Parse(json);
        var details = obj["response"]["details"];

        Console.WriteLine(details);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know, I'm unfamiliar with it. I would like to keep using a stream instead of converting to a string. I also used a simplified example. I use more converters for things like converting an array of dictionaries to an array of their values and converting unix timestamps to date objects.

Comment: @Mark So you want a solution to a problem you can't solve but don't want to change how you work? Interesting.

Comment: But perhaps fair enough, a stream is more useful for some scenarios.

Comment: @Gusdor I was asking how to make use of a `JsonConverter` to accomplish this. I wanted to understand why my code was not working and what was wrong with my approach. That is of higher importance to me than finding a fix to the underlying issue of an undesirable JSON format from the response.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want a single value from the details array, so my answer just takes the first. Would a converter like this work? It takes the JObject and picks out a single value from the details array, and then converts that into the Details class.

```
public class DetailsConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(Details) == objectType;
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var obj = JObject.Load(reader);
        var value = obj["response"]?["details"]?.FirstOrDefault();
        if (value == null) { return null; }
        return value.ToObject<Details>();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

When you use the serializer, you can simply call it like this:

`var details = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Details>(json, settings);`

Note that you need to create `JsonSerializerSettings settings`, and include DetailsConverter in the Converters list of the settings object.